# ImageView vertically centred in MaterialCardView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android

Objective: I am trying to make a MaterialCard with an Image inside it, as well as some text below the Image. This current layout will serve as a "menu" for the application, where the user can select where to navigate to.

Problem: The ImageView is appearing vertically centred in the MaterialCardView. I would like the ImageView to "stick" to the top of the MaterialCardView. There are large sections of MaterialCardView above and below the ImageView.

My XML Code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:liftOnScroll="true"
            android:id="@+id/appBar">

            <Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/application_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>

            </Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/mealPlannerCardView"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/wedding_dinner"
                android:contentDescription="@string/wedding_background_cont_desc"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/mealPlannerTextView"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"/>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20TSv.png)

I tried to use `layout_gravity="Top"` but it made no difference.

**EDIT**

`android:scaleType="fitStart"` made the Image "stick" to the TOP of the MaterialCardView, but now very large space beneath the ImageView that requires scrolling to get to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line below in your xml

```
android:layout_gravity="start|top"
```

See if this repositions the image for you. Worry about centring later if this works.

Comment: doesn't work

image still in the middle of app with big gaps on top and bottom

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitStart"` made the Image "stick" to the TOP of the MaterialCardView, but now very large space beneath the ImageView that requires scrolling to get to end.

Comment: how about adding fix no of px to : tolayout_height="wrap_content | 300px"

Comment: Also what is best and easy way to test this xml code.  I am a full stack developer use visual studio code not set up with Java on this at this time. Do have eclipse. Is their a free online tool to test the xml code for android? I mostly do web apps that are responsive and PWAs.

Answer (score 0):

You might get the result you want by setting a scaleType for the image view.
Checkout this link: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

It shows examples of each scaleType, it will help you to choose the right one to achieve the appearance you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the Android framework is trying to maintain the aspect ratio in the face of your height and width constraints and default scale type.

There are more than one solutions to your problem and its for you to choose based on whose results are acceptable to you. All these solutions revolve around helping the framework with ImageView's aspect ratio. Let me try to put down the possible solutions that I can think of.

1. First solution can be as simple as changing the scale type on your ImageView as below:

   ```
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/wedding_dinner"/>
   ```

That will take away the white spaces but crop your image.

2. A slight variation of the above, where you can define a fixed height of the image. This is a surprisingly widely used solution as it provides a certain

   ```
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="240dp"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/wedding_dinner"/>
   ```
3. Finally, a more elegant and better solution is to provide a fixed aspect ratio to your images using a ConstrainLayout.